# Techniques for training a CV model based on PDF markup

Tags: cnn, computer-vision, opencv

Given a PDF of a home blueprint (e.g. https://www.roomsketcher.com/content/uploads/2023/04/blueprint-maker.jpg), what are techniques and approaches for training a CV model to lean how a user would trace different parts of blueprint (e.g. a room, walls, spaces, etc.)?